# Parse Google Trends API data into JSON format

Tags: node.js, json, api, parsing, google-trends

I was working on a program which fetches the data from Google Trends API using Node.js, I am getting the desired data, but not in the correct format. I want to do JSON parsing so that I can get data in the correct format.

My code:

```
//This program is fetching data from google trend api for a particular job title
var googleTrends = require('google-trends-api');
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('keywords.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
        }
        data = data.toString().split("\n");
        recur(0, data);
});

function recur(index, data){
        if (index < data.length){
                var keyword = data[index].split(",");

                 console.log(keyword);
                googleTrends.interestByRegion({keyword:keyword,
                geo:'US',
                resolution:'state'
                })

                .then(function(results ){

                  console.log(results+ "\n");


                  console.log("***********************************************************************************************");

                  index = index+1;

                    recur(index, data);
                         })
                .catch(function(err){
                        console.error('We have an error!', err);
                 });
        }

}
```

Output :-

> [ 'House Cleaning' ]
>   {"default":{"geoMapData":[{"geoCode":"US-CO","geoName":"Colorado","value":[100],"formattedValue":["100"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-AZ","geoName":"Arizona","value":[96],"formattedValue":["96"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-WA","geoName":"Washington","value":[95],"formattedValue":["95"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-KS","geoName":"Kansas","value":[93],"formattedValue":["93"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-NV","geoName":"Nevada","value":[93],"formattedValue":["93"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-ID","geoName":"Idaho","value":[93],"formattedValue":["93"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-RI","geoName":"Rhode
>   Island","value":[87],"formattedValue":["87"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-UT","geoName":"Utah","value":[86],"formattedValue":["86"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-OR","geoName":"Oregon","value":[85],"formattedValue":["85"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-OK","geoName":"Oklahoma","value":[83],"formattedValue":["83"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-NC","geoName":"North
>   Carolina","value":[83],"formattedValue":["83"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-TN","geoName":"Tennessee","value":[80],"formattedValue":["80"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-CA","geoName":"California","value":[79],"formattedValue":["79"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-GA","geoName":"Georgia","value":[78],"formattedValue":["78"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-TX","geoName":"Texas","value":[78],"formattedValue":["78"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-MO","geoName":"Missouri","value":[77],"formattedValue":["77"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-MT","geoName":"Montana","value":[77],"formattedValue":["77"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-NH","geoName":"New
>   Hampshire","value":[76],"formattedValue":["76"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-SC","geoName":"South
>   Carolina","value":[76],"formattedValue":["76"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-AL","geoName":"Alabama","value":[75],"formattedValue":["75"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-MA","geoName":"Massachusetts","value":[75],"formattedValue":["75"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-FL","geoName":"Florida","value":[75],"formattedValue":["75"],"maxValueIndex":0,"hasData":[true]},{"geoCode":"US-AR","geoName":"Arkansas","value":

Comment: The API you are uing returns response in correct JSON format so you probably mess it up by appending some additional strings to it like so `[ 'House Cleaning' ] {"default":{"geoMapData":[{"geoCode":"US-`